# Encountered the symbol \"CLOSE\" after prepareCall

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, callable-statement

[pl/sql code TRIGER1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1unmb6fESzEllwtF0RTUdSBk3Y83r26CkLzzGiZ-exDQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my pl/sql code that I am trying to execute by `prepareCall`

```
String sql = String.format(FunctionCalls.TRIGGER1);
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
Integer result = null;
String err = null;
try {
    callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(sql);

    callableStatement.execute();
    result = callableStatement.getInt("RES_CODE");
    err = callableStatement.getString("RES_DESC" );
```

After executing, I want to get two of the declared parameters, `RES_CODE` and `RES_DESC`, but I get this error instead:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 1274:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol \"CLOSE\" \n

After googling, many people think that the problem is in cursor that you need to declare cursors in declaration section and the process cursor after BEGIN, but I am doing аs it says. In PL/SQL Developer it works fine you can see in image.

[image: the image]

Is it possible in java get declared parameter after execute ?

Is it possible execute TRIGER1 pl/sql code and get the two parameters `RES_CODE` and `RES_DESC`?

Comment: Please post the actual code your executing (minimize it to reduce length), questions should not rely on external links for pertinent information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As javadoc of [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) says: *"The interface used to execute SQL **stored procedures**."*

The javadoc even shows the syntax you must use, which starts with a `{` brace.

Your SQL is **not** a *stored procedure*, it is a *PL/SQL block*.
Also, `RES_CODE` and `RES_DESC` are **not** *parameters*.

What you're trying to do is entirely wrong, and if some site has shown you to do it this way, please stop using that site *immediately*.

Try actually *creating* a stored procedure with the code in question, and define actual parameters to that store procedure.

[Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373) for that is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xxx ( RES_CODE OUT number, RES_DESC OUT varchar2 ) AS
  variable declarations here
BEGIN
  code here
END;
/
```

Then you call that procedure using:

```
String sql = "{call xxx(?,?)}";
try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql)) {
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, TYPES.INTEGER);
    stmt.registerOutParameter(2, TYPES.VARCHAR);
    stmt.execute();
    result = stmt.getInt(1);
    err = stmt.getString(2);
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer . I can't create any procedure in this db .I can only call functions, procedures and run selects . If so then how can i run this from java ?